# CSS Grid how to push items to the bottom and then to the left

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with 5 buttons with only 2 buttons per row. If there's an odd number of buttons I want the first row to only have one button.

My css:

```css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>C</button>
    <button>D</button>
    <button>E</button>
</div>
```

Layout:

```
A B
C D
E
```

Desired Layout:

```
A
B C
D E
```

Comment: I would say css *is* conditional, but maybe not enough for this task.

Comment: Might not be a bad idea to use flexbox for this

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, it can be done. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In other words, you want your second button, when it is in an even position counting from the last, to be in the first column:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container button:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
  <button>D</button>
  <button>E</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
  <button>D</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A flexbox idea:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container button {
  width:50%;
}

.container button:first-child:nth-last-child(odd) {
  margin-right:1px; /* a tiny margin to push the next element */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
  <button>D</button>
  <button>E</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
  <button>D</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
</div>
```